# Dirac measure and it's associated functional

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $I(f) = f(x_0)$ for any $f \in C_c(X)$. Prove the Dirac mass at $x_0 \in X$ is the Radon measure associated with this positive linear function $I: C_c(X) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$.

I'm not sure if I did this correctly, so I wanted to check:

Clearly $I$ is linear and positive so by the Riesz Representation Theorem, there is a unique Radon measure $\nu$ so that $I(f) = \int f d\nu$ for all $f \in C_c(X)$. So if $\nu$ were the Dirac mass at $x_0$, I'd get:

$$I(f) = \int f d\delta_{x_0} = f(x_0)$$

So since the Radon measure is unique and the Dirac measure satisfies the associated linear functional I want, I'm done.